# Usage of "wish" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood, wish-preterite

I want to make a sentence with "wish".

If someone is leaving tomorrow and I want him not to leave. What sentence should be correct using "wish":

I wish you were not leaving tomorrow

OR

I wish you would not leave tomorrow.

Comment: Both are correct uses of "wish" and basically say the same thing.

Comment: Furthermore, at the time of writing this comment the question has been starred by 4 people. It shows there is interest in this question.

Comment: What makes me wrong @Nico?  Those sentences are perfectly grammatical and correct.

Comment: The typical example is that we shouldn't say "I wish I wouldn’t eat so much chocolate". We should say instead "I wish I didn’t eat so much chocolate".

Comment: @KristinaLopez, I've removed one of my comments an rephrased so as not to make it personal

Comment: Considering that none of the answers, including mine, get to clearly pinpoint the difference between these two constructions, I see the need for this question. Rather than removing, I would suggest to transfer the question to ELL.

Comment: @Nico, that's fine, I don't mind it being personal, I was just curious what was "wrong" with the sentences.  I guess as a native speaker who is not an English major, I don't remember hearing that we shouldn't use "wish" & "wouldn't".  I learned something new today! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez I've found an answer on ELL for this question. See [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17272/4559)

Answer (score 0):

I think both sentences are grammatically correct.

In my opinion, I prefer the first one, "I wish you weren't leaving tomorrow", or making a little change to second sentence,"I wish you would stay tomorrow".

Answer (score 0):

yup both the sentences are correct and are green to use.
But I suggest the use of second one because leaving is an action which is to be performed by a person and you want that person to not perform this action instead of the event of leaving.
So better to use 2nd sentence to emphasize the action.

another option is to say:
"How I wish you don't leave tomorrow."

Else both are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are grammatically correct but they have different meanings:

> I wish you weren't leaving tomorrow

In this case, you express your regret that something is happening in the future.

> I wish you would not leave tomorrow

But in this case, what you regret is that the other person **wants** to leave the day after.

Comment: +1 I also think the second carries more of a plea for them to stay.

Comment: Why the downvote?